# c++ poco mingw linking problems: undefined reference

Tags: c++, mingw, poco-libraries

I have downloaded and compiled **poco 1.8.1** on **win7** with **mingw32** in **qtcreator** with **cmake**, using these options:

```
ENABLE_DATA, ENABLE_JSON, ENABLE_NET, ENABLE_UTIL, POCO_STATIC
```

Then it generated to me these files:

```
libPocoFoundationd.a, libPocoJSONd.a, libPocoNetd.a, libPocoUtild.a
```

Then, I want to use it in executable project. This is how its .pro file is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          +=  -std=c++0x

LIBS += -L"$$PWD/../../../poco/build/Debug/lib" -lPocoUtild -lPocoJSONd -lPocoNetd -lPocoFoundationd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/build/Debug
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/build/Debug

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/net/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/foundation/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/json/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../poco/util/include

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/''
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/''
```

I want to compile an example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServer.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequestHandlerFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPServerParams.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/WebSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/NetException.h"
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"
#include "Poco/Util/Option.h"
#include "Poco/Util/OptionSet.h"
#include "Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/Format.h"
#include <iostream>


using Poco::Net::ServerSocket;
using Poco::Net::WebSocket;
using Poco::Net::WebSocketException;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler;
using Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory;
using Poco::Net::HTTPServer;
using Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest;
using Poco::Net::HTTPResponse;
using Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse;
using Poco::Net::HTTPServerParams;
using Poco::Timestamp;
using Poco::ThreadPool;
using Poco::Util::ServerApplication;
using Poco::Util::Application;
using Poco::Util::Option;
using Poco::Util::OptionSet;
using Poco::Util::HelpFormatter;

using namespace std;

class PageRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
    /// Return a HTML document with some JavaScript creating
    /// a WebSocket connection.
{
public:
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        std::ostream& ostr = response.send();
        ostr << "<html>";
        ostr << "<head>";
        ostr << "<title>WebSocketServer</title>";
        ostr << "<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
        ostr << "function WebSocketTest()";
        ostr << "{";
        ostr << "  if (\"WebSocket\" in window)";
        ostr << "  {";
        ostr << "    var ws = new WebSocket(\"ws://" << request.serverAddress().toString() << "/ws\");";
        ostr << "    ws.onopen = function()";
        ostr << "      {";
        ostr << "        ws.send(\"Hello, world!\");";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "    ws.onmessage = function(evt)";
        ostr << "      { ";
        ostr << "        var msg = evt.data;";
        ostr << "        alert(\"Message received: \" + msg);";
        ostr << "        ws.close();";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "    ws.onclose = function()";
        ostr << "      { ";
        ostr << "        alert(\"WebSocket closed.\");";
        ostr << "      };";
        ostr << "  }";
        ostr << "  else";
        ostr << "  {";
        ostr << "     alert(\"This browser does not support WebSockets.\");";
        ostr << "  }";
        ostr << "}";
        ostr << "</script>";
        ostr << "</head>";
        ostr << "<body>";
        ostr << "  <h1>WebSocket Server</h1>";
        ostr << "  <p><a href=\"javascript:WebSocketTest()\">Run WebSocket Script</a></p>";
        ostr << "</body>";
        ostr << "</html>";
    }
};


class WebSocketRequestHandler: public HTTPRequestHandler
    /// Handle a WebSocket connection.
{
public:
    void handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        try
        {
            WebSocket ws(request, response);
            app.logger().information("WebSocket connection established.");
            char buffer[1024];
            int flags;
            int n;
            do
            {
                n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
                app.logger().information(Poco::format("Frame received (length=%d, flags=0x%x).", n, unsigned(flags)));
                ws.sendFrame(buffer, n, flags);
            }
            while (n > 0 && (flags & WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) != WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CLOSE);
            app.logger().information("WebSocket connection closed.");
        }
        catch (WebSocketException& exc)
        {
            app.logger().log(exc);
            switch (exc.code())
            {
            case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION:
                response.set("Sec-WebSocket-Version", WebSocket::WEBSOCKET_VERSION);
                // fallthrough
            case WebSocket::WS_ERR_NO_HANDSHAKE:
            case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_VERSION:
            case WebSocket::WS_ERR_HANDSHAKE_NO_KEY:
                response.setStatusAndReason(HTTPResponse::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
                response.setContentLength(0);
                response.send();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};


class RequestHandlerFactory: public HTTPRequestHandlerFactory
{
public:
    HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const HTTPServerRequest& request)
    {
        Application& app = Application::instance();
        app.logger().information("Request from "
            + request.clientAddress().toString()
            + ": "
            + request.getMethod()
            + " "
            + request.getURI()
            + " "
            + request.getVersion());

        for (HTTPServerRequest::ConstIterator it = request.begin(); it != request.end(); ++it)
        {
            app.logger().information(it->first + ": " + it->second);
        }

        if(request.find("Upgrade") != request.end() && Poco::icompare(request["Upgrade"], "websocket") == 0)
            return new WebSocketRequestHandler;
        else
            return new PageRequestHandler;
    }
};


class WebSocketServer: public Poco::Util::ServerApplication
    /// The main application class.
    ///
    /// This class handles command-line arguments and
    /// configuration files.
    /// Start the WebSocketServer executable with the help
    /// option (/help on Windows, --help on Unix) for
    /// the available command line options.
    ///
    /// To use the sample configuration file (WebSocketServer.properties),
    /// copy the file to the directory where the WebSocketServer executable
    /// resides. If you start the debug version of the WebSocketServer
    /// (WebSocketServerd[.exe]), you must also create a copy of the configuration
    /// file named WebSocketServerd.properties. In the configuration file, you
    /// can specify the port on which the server is listening (default
    /// 9980) and the format of the date/time string sent back to the client.
    ///
    /// To test the WebSocketServer you can use any web browser (http://localhost:9980/).
{
public:
    WebSocketServer(): _helpRequested(false)
    {
    }

    ~WebSocketServer()
    {
    }

protected:
    void initialize(Application& self)
    {
        loadConfiguration(); // load default configuration files, if present
        ServerApplication::initialize(self);
    }

    void uninitialize()
    {
        ServerApplication::uninitialize();
    }

    void defineOptions(OptionSet& options)
    {
        ServerApplication::defineOptions(options);

        options.addOption(
            Option("help", "h", "display help information on command line arguments")
                .required(false)
                .repeatable(false));
    }

    void handleOption(const std::string& name, const std::string& value)
    {
        ServerApplication::handleOption(name, value);

        if (name == "help")
            _helpRequested = true;
    }

    void displayHelp()
    {
        HelpFormatter helpFormatter(options());
        helpFormatter.setCommand(commandName());
        helpFormatter.setUsage("OPTIONS");
        helpFormatter.setHeader("A sample HTTP server supporting the WebSocket protocol.");
        helpFormatter.format(std::cout);
    }

    int main(const std::vector<std::string>& args)
    {
        if (_helpRequested)
        {
            displayHelp();
        }
        else
        {
            // get parameters from configuration file
            unsigned short port = (unsigned short) config().getInt("WebSocketServer.port", 9980);

            // set-up a server socket
            ServerSocket svs(port);
            // set-up a HTTPServer instance
            HTTPServer srv(new RequestHandlerFactory, svs, new HTTPServerParams);
            // start the HTTPServer
            srv.start();
            // wait for CTRL-C or kill
            waitForTerminationRequest();
            // Stop the HTTPServer
            srv.stop();
        }
        return Application::EXIT_OK;
    }

private:
    bool _helpRequested;
};


POCO_SERVER_MAIN(WebSocketServer)
```

But of course, nothing works. I got undefined references. Actually, every thing is undefined:

```
Timestamp.h:256:28: warning: 'static Poco::Timestamp::TimeDiff Poco::Timestamp::resolution()' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
 inline Timestamp::TimeDiff Timestamp::resolution()
                            ^                                              ^
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\use_poco.exe debug/main.o  - -lPocoUtild -lPocoJSONd -lPocoNetd -lPocoFoundationd 
debug/main.o: In function `wmain':
use_poco/main.cpp:260: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco4Util17ServerApplication3runEiPPw'
use_poco/main.cpp:260: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK4Poco9Exception11displayTextEv'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN4Poco6Logger3logERKSsNS_7Message8PriorityE':
Poco/Logger.h:671: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco7MessageC1ERKSsS2_NS0_8PriorityE'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN4Poco4Util11Application8instanceEv':
Poco/Util/Application.h:453: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco4Util11Application10_pInstanceE'
Poco/Util/Application.h:454: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco4Util11Application10_pInstanceE'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN18PageRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE':
use_poco/main.cpp:49: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN4Poco3Net11HTTPMessage14setContentTypeERKSs'
use_poco/main.cpp:59: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK4Poco3Net13SocketAddress8toStringEv'
debug/main.o: In function `ZN23WebSocketRequestHandler13handleRequestERN4Poco3Net17HTTPServerRequestERNS1_18HTTPServerResponseE':
...
...
poco/Util/src/Application.cpp:82: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
poco/Util/src/Application.cpp:83: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
poco\build\Debug\lib/libPocoUtild.a(Application.cpp.obj): In function `ZN4Poco4Util11ApplicationD2Ev':
...
...
```

I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637797/compile-poco-with-mingw-on-windows/14647307#14647307), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363646/compiling-c11-with-g), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833617/build-errors-c-with-poco-and-qt-creator), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701796/poco-c-static-linking-problems-with-undefined-references-to-symbols) with no result.

How could I use poco?

Comment: Make sure you are using the same compiler , build options and defines for compiling POCO as you did for compiling your project. E.g. I don't see `POCO_STATIC` in your .pro file . The error messages suggest it's trying to link against DLL import library (which is the default behaviour if you didn't specify POCO_STATIC)

Comment: I have done double check, with no luck. The .dll version works, but static, never.